# how can i scrape the all courses from the website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I want to scrape every course name on this page [this page][1] Here is my code

```
URL = 'https://www.bachelorsportal.com/search/bachelors-degrees/computer-science-it/#q=di-24|lv-bachelor?'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.findAll(class_='StudyTitle')
print(results)
```

i'm getting empty array

Comment: the search result content might be dynamically rendered with JS so there's no tag with the given id

Comment: how can i scrap the courses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @baduker is right, the courses' content gets dynamically loaded thru JS. See the  URL's main request **empty response**:

[image]

The obvious solution is to use a browser automation by selenium (eg. headless Chrome).

### Hack

You might find the XHR/Ajax requests that return courses' content (as json) and [perform them by Python](https://webscraping.pro/scrape-lazy-load-page-python-requests/) to fetch content.